# Line gap in CSS

Tags: css

There is a line gap between first line to second line. How to remove it?

```css
ol {
  color: #fff;
  list-style-type: decimal;
  background: #152a40;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 1.2em 30px 1.2em 75px;
  line-height: 0;
}

ol li {
  position: relative;
  font: bold italic 45px/1.5 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

li p {
  font: 15px/1.5 Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding-left: 60px;
  color: #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent euismod ultrices ante, ac laoreet nulla vestibulum adipiscing. Nam quis justo in augue auctor imperdiet. Curabitur aliquet orci sit amet est posuere consectetur. Fusce nec leo ut massa
      viverra venenatis. Nam accumsan libero a elit aliquet quis ullamcorper arcu tincidunt. Praesent purus turpis, consectetur quis congue vel, pulvinar at lorem. Vivamus varius condimentum dolor, quis ultricies ipsum porta quis. </p>
  </li>

  <li>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent euismod ultrices ante, ac laoreet nulla vestibulum adipiscing. Nam quis justo in augue auctor imperdiet. Curabitur aliquet orci sit amet est posuere consectetur. </p>
  </li>

  <li>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent euismod ultrices ante, ac laoreet nulla vestibulum adipiscing. Nam quis justo in augue auctor imperdiet. Curabitur aliquet orci sit amet est posuere consectetur. </p>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: reset `margin`s of `p` elements...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue originates from the fact that the list item's counter is actually part of the DOM node: therefore, increasing it's font size and therefore its line-height will actually influence how the first line looks like.

For a fool-proof setup, you will want to **isolate the counter from the actual `<li>` content**. In order to do this, we can use [CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters).

1. Declare a custom counter (let's name it `listCounter`) on the parent element (`<ol>` in this case), so that it is reset for each occurrence, e.g. `counter-reset: listCounter`.
2. Increment the counter in the nested `<li>` elements, using: `counter-increment: listCounter;`. Also, since we are using custom counters, disable the default counter using `list-style: none`.
3. Use `::before` pseudo-element on the `<li>` element to display our custom counter, using `content: counter(listCounter)`.

Here is a proof-of-concept example:

```css
ol {
  color: #fff;
  list-style-type: decimal;
  background: #152a40;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 1.2em 30px 1.2em 75px;
  line-height: 0;
  
  /* Reset counter */
  counter-reset: listCounter;  
}

ol li {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  
  /* Increment counter by 1 in each <li> */
  counter-increment: listCounter;
  
  /* Hide default bullets/list counter */
  list-style: none;
  
  /*
  * Top padding to accommodate tall list counter
  * This value is a trial and error value, used to align baselines of counter and paragraph's first line
  */
  padding-top: 18px;
}

ol li::before {
  /* Set pseudo-element's content as counter */
  content: counter(listCounter) ".";
  
  font: bold italic 45px/1.5 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  
  /* Positioning, you decide how you want it to look */
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  top: 0;
}

li p {
  font: 15px/1.5 Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding-left: 60px;
  color: #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent euismod ultrices ante, ac laoreet nulla vestibulum adipiscing. Nam quis justo in augue auctor imperdiet. Curabitur aliquet orci sit amet est posuere consectetur. Fusce nec leo ut massa
      viverra venenatis. Nam accumsan libero a elit aliquet quis ullamcorper arcu tincidunt. Praesent purus turpis, consectetur quis congue vel, pulvinar at lorem. Vivamus varius condimentum dolor, quis ultricies ipsum porta quis. </p>
  </li>

  <li>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent euismod ultrices ante, ac laoreet nulla vestibulum adipiscing. Nam quis justo in augue auctor imperdiet. Curabitur aliquet orci sit amet est posuere consectetur. </p>
  </li>

  <li>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent euismod ultrices ante, ac laoreet nulla vestibulum adipiscing. Nam quis justo in augue auctor imperdiet. Curabitur aliquet orci sit amet est posuere consectetur. </p>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Hi, i implemented here http://einsty.com/crossy-road-game-wiki/  please check the list, now the problem is last list number 14, if data is more it should go to next line but it is not going.. text is overlapping

Comment: @AnuragKumar Remove `line-height: 0` on your `<ol>` element, or wrap the inner content of your `<li>` element with `<p>` (you did that in your question, but not on your site markup).

Comment: Hi, actually it is wordpress, and there is no <p> there in <li>. I thought p was there. Thanks it worked..

Answer (score 1):

The first line has a larger line height because of the large number in the list. You can resolve this issue by adding `line-height: 1;` to the `ol li`

```
ol li {
  position: relative;
  font: bold italic 45px/1.5 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears the issue is with the `font-size/line-height` between the `li` and the `p`. Set the `line-height` for the `li` and `p` to a closer value, or `1` for the `li`, and use `margin` to separate the `li` items.

```css
ol {
  color: #fff;
  list-style-type: decimal;
  background: #152a40;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 1.2em 30px 1.2em 75px;
  line-height: 0;
}

ol li {
  position: relative;
  font: bold italic 45px/1 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

li p {
  font: 15px/1.5 Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding-left: 60px;
  color: #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent euismod ultrices ante, ac laoreet nulla vestibulum adipiscing. Nam quis justo in augue auctor imperdiet. Curabitur aliquet orci sit amet est posuere consectetur. Fusce nec leo ut massa viverra venenatis. Nam accumsan libero a elit aliquet quis ullamcorper arcu tincidunt. Praesent purus turpis, consectetur quis congue vel, pulvinar at lorem. Vivamus varius condimentum dolor, quis ultricies ipsum porta quis. </p>
  </li>

  <li>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent euismod ultrices ante, ac laoreet nulla vestibulum adipiscing. Nam quis justo in augue auctor imperdiet. Curabitur aliquet orci sit amet est posuere consectetur. </p>
  </li>

  <li>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent euismod ultrices ante, ac laoreet nulla vestibulum adipiscing. Nam quis justo in augue auctor imperdiet. Curabitur aliquet orci sit amet est posuere consectetur. </p>
  </li>
</ol>
```